# Correct pattern for refreshing data in UIViewController's

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I am trying to refresh my view data when the application becomes the active app again. I believe the correct pattern is to have the app delegate tell it's view to reload it's data when applicationDidBecomeActive is called.

However, I am having trouble finding the UIViewController from within the Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    MyFancyViewController* controller = //how do I get my view controller???
    [controller refreshData];
}
```

Also, can I count on the view controller still being allocated, or is there a chance it would go away? I'm using iOS 5 Storyboard's if that makes any difference.

Update:
I think I got it:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIViewController* root = _window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)root;
    OctainViewController* mycontroller = (OctainViewController*)[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [mycontroller refresh:nil];
}
```

Comment: You can also post an notification from applicationDidBecomeActive() and handle it in respective tableviewcontroller.

Comment: You can post a notification using NSNotification center. Register your viewcontrollers for notifications and post notification from applicationDidBecomeActive() method. http://www.gnu.org/software/gnustep/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSNotification.html

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this does the trick:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{  
    UIViewController* root = _window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)root;
    OctainViewController* mycontroller = (OctainViewController*)[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [mycontroller refresh:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not refresh your data in the respective view controller viewWillAppear method?

Comment: That isn't called when the app comes back from the background. Only the delegate's applicationDidBecomeActive.